# Map Color Texture to closest color in a palette

Tags: node-editor, color

I have an image texture and a list of RGB values of some dozen colors. I was wondering if there's a way to "map" each color of my original texture to the closest color in the palette, using nodes in the shader editor.
I tried adding each color in my list to a constant color ramp, and plugging my original texture into its factor but the result is not what I was looking for:
[image: My node setup]

Before adding the color ramp:

[image: Before adding the color ramp]

After:

[image]

Which is not what I was looking for... As you can see the greys were mapped to the reds, the dark greys to the whites etc.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Why not import the palette into a graphic editor like Gimp and reduce the colors of your image to your palette?

Comment: Because I want to generalize it for any image texture. For context, I have a geometry nodes set-up that turns any model into Legos. I want to be able to plug any model to those nodes and convert its colors to the limited Lego palette, which is what I have in the Color Ramp.